# Работа с разными версиями python3 в AstraLinux CommonEdition

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyqt5, astra-linux

В AstraLinux изначально установлен python3.5. Версию 3.7 установил с помощью менеджера пакетов Synaptic.

Имеется простой код на языке python с библиотекой PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если запустить файл с исходным кодом так:
**python3.5 test.py** - всё работает.
Если же я запускаю **python3.7 test.py** - в консоли выводится такая надпись: *ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWidgets' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/**init**.py)*

Как сделать так, чтобы версия python3.7 смогла увидеть установленные пакеты и библиотеки?
Пробовал работу с командой update-alternatives, назначал приоритеты, но проблему это не решило.

Comment: Самый простой вариант, ИМХО, - сделайте себе venv в python 3.7, установите в него все необходимые пакеты и работайте в созданном venv.

Comment: Во время создания виртуального окружения _python3.7 -m venv venv_ сообщение:
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/adminus/Документы/venv/bin/python3.7', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']

Comment: python3-venv установлен

Comment: Если вы установили более новый пайтон из пакетов, то соответствующий `venv`, скорее всего, называется `python3.7-venv`

Comment: проверил этот вариант: Уже установлен пакет python3.7-venv самой новой версии (3.7.3-2+deb10u3+ci202107011746+astra2).

Comment: Может быть, вам переустановить `python 3.7`?

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал в Ubuntu 18: установил пакеты `python3.7` и `python3.7-venv`, затем попробовал создать виртуальное окружение. Сработало легко и непринуждённо.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу помощь! Что то не так с этой астрой. Переустановил  python3.7. Опять хочу создать виртуальное окружение - ругается:                                                                 _The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment._

Comment: Вы переустановили оба пакета - `python3.7` и `python3.7-venv`, правильно? 
Команду запускаете с полным именем `/usr/bin/python3.7 -m venv venv-3.7`?

Comment: Точно так! Переустановил оба пакета, запускаю питон через указание полного пути. Всё также

Comment: Что-то у вас радикально сломано )
Попробуйте снести вообще все пайтоны и поставить их заново.

Comment: Есть родной python3.5. Если его удалять он за собой тащит очень много всего

Comment: И кстати с 3.5 вообще никаких проблем, разве что он сильно устарел...

Comment: План Б. Добавьте в ваш вопрос вывод вот такой команды: `python3.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`. Если в нём есть путь `/usr/lib/python3.7`, убедитесь, что в этой папке есть `ensurepip`. Если `ensurepip` там нет, значит `python3.7-venv` встал криво. Если пути `/usr/lib/python3.7` там нет, то `venv` нужно создавать командой `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.7 python3.7 -m venv venv`

Comment: вывод команды: _['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/adminus/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']_

Comment: В каталоге /usr/lib/python3.7 присутствует каталог _ensurepip_. В нем находится каталог __pycache__ и файлы: __init.py   __main__.py _uninstall.py

Answer (score 1):

Проблему с созданием окружения для *Python3.7* в **`AstraLinux`** решил созданием окружения без модуля **`pip`**, но доступом к системным пакетам,

где **`pip`** есть:

*python3.7 –m venv --without-pip --system-site-packages*

Установка модулей из активированного окружения:

*python3 –m pip install <modul_name>*

Answer (score 0):

Если вы установили более новый пайтон из пакетов, то соответствующий `venv`, скорее всего, называется `python3.7-venv`

С развёртыванием виртуального окружения есть одна тонкость. `venv` делает копию установки `python`, собранной саппортерами из дистрибутива. Но они всегда на несколько поколений позади актуальных версий. Поэтому перед практическим использованием `venv` необходимо обновить системные пакеты.

Я покажу на примере `python-3.8`, который стоит у меня в Ubuntu, но у вас последовательность шагов будет точно такой же.

1. Создать виртуальное окружение:
   `$ /usr/bin/python-3.8 -m venv ~/tmp/venv-3.8`
2. Активировать это окружение в текущем сеансе `bash`:
   `$ source ~/tmp/venv-3.8/bin/activate`

   По этой команде в текущем сеансе будут прописаны переменные окружения, указывающие на бинарники, библиотеки и пакеты в каталоге `~/tmp/venv-3.8/`
3. Для проверки: `(venv-3.8) $ which python3` -> `/home/user/tmp/venv-3.8/bin/python3`

   Обратите внимание, что `activate` изменил строку приглашения в `bash`, добавив в неё указание, что в текущем сеансе активно виртуальное окружение.
4. Первым делом нужно обновить `pip` и `setuptools`:

   `(venv-3.8) $ pip3 install pip setuptools --upgrade`

   Не знаю, как у вас в Астре, а у меня в Убунте в пакетах идёт совершенно допотопный `pip` версии 9. Текущий `pip` версии 21.2. `setuptools` апгрейдятся с версии 39 до 58.
5. Теперь можно устанавливать `pyqt5` и все остальные пакеты, необходимые вам. Устанавливать через `pip`! не через пакеты дистрибутива:

   `(venv-3.8) $ pip3 install pyqt5`
6. После установки всех пакетов запускаете ваш скрипт в активированном окружении: `(venv-3.8) $ python3 test.py`
7. Если вам нужно отменить изменения переменных окружения, внесённые скриптом `activate`, выполните команду `(venv-3.8) $ deactivate` и все исходные настройки вернутся.

Для 3.6 вы можете создать такое же окружение в отдельной папке, и выполнять `test.py`, активировав его. Так вы полностью разделите пакеты между версиями пайтона.

Пустое виртуальное окружение весит меньше 10 Мб, но, разумеется, по мере установки пакетов, будет раздуваться. Например, у меня установлены `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `tensorflow`, `jupyter` - размер `venv` почти 1.8 гб.

Comment: Собрал из исходников python3.8. Создаю виртуальное окружение. Все хорошо. Версия pip 21.1.1 from /home/adminus/Документы/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8).  При попытке установить pyqt5 опять ругается: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Comment: Значит вы собрали пайтон без поддержки SSL. `$ sudo apt get libssl-dev`  затем пересоберите `python`: `$ ./configure --with-ssl`

Comment: библиотеку libssl-dev поставил. А вот при конфигурации сборки ругается на ключ --with-ssl

Comment: @Анатолий Да, действительно, `--with-ssl` больше не нужно указывать. `configure` автоматически найдёт `libssl` и пайтон будет собран с поддержкой SSL.

Comment: после команды make появилось такое сообщение: _Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381_

Comment: буду копать openssl